# Как собрать проект Maven

Tags: java, maven

Не могу понять как правильно собирать проект. Допустим у меня есть папка "Сервер" в котором есть 3 отдельных проекта maven. Проекты А и Б зависят от С. Раньше я просто подключал jar-файлы в идее. Теперь мне нужно передать это все на другой компьютер, и чтобы там все собралось. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Где-то прочитал, что можно какой-нибудь модуль установить в локальный репозиторий, а потом сослаться на него в другом проекте как на dependency. Но как тогда проект соберется на другом компе?

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Передайте все проекты, а потом устанавливайте их по очереди и подключайте как dependency.

К примеру, у вас проекты А и Б независимы друг от друга, но зависимы от С.

Тогда : Устанавливаем проект С в локальный репозиторий (mvn install).

Затем собираем проект А и проект Б  ( в их помах проект С должен быть подключен как dependency) .

Если попытаться изменить порядок сборки, и установить сначало А и Б , то билд зафейлится, потому что С еще не установлено.

Когда у вас проект мульти-модульный и существует иерархия (скажем А главный модуль, С и Б его потомки), тогда мавен сам определяет порядок сборки.

Answer (score 0):

Для сборки таких проектов в Maven есть специальный механизм, который называется Reactor. см. [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). Здесь есть аналогичный вопрос с ответами [How to structure a multi-modules Maven project to compile it at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034544/how-to-structure-a-multi-modules-maven-project-to-compile-it-at-once)